# Android : button for decline the incoming call

Tags: android, button

When there is a incoming call and the phone is ringing, I want to display a button into dialog over the incoming call screen for to decline and finish the incoming call, it's possibile ?

Comment: Isn't there a decline button anyway?! Why disturbing the user by a custom popup when he's used to see his usual UI? Or am I getting the wrong idea?

Comment: Please, do not create apps that, without UI triggered action, pop in front of default app and start making mess. We, users, do not like this.

Comment: This question is only for to know if it's possibile to do it because I must create an application that decline an incaming call and automatically recall the phone number after a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but it requires Java Reflection to access hidden classes in the Android Telephony Framework (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) - which means that it could well break with new Android versions.

See http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html for a good how-to.